# Lista de structs

Tags: c, struct, lista-encadeada

Gostaria de saber qual a vantagem de se utilizar uma lista dessa maneira.

```
typedef struct Pessoas {

    char nome[20];
    int idade;
    struct Pessoas *prox;
}pessoas;

typedef struct Funcionario {
    pessoas *pessoa;
    struct Funcionario *prox;
}funcionario;
```

Para apenas uma struct de Funcionario.

Fiz essa declaração de inserir, mas não sei é correta:

```
funcionario* adicionar(pessoas *p, char *nome, int idade) {

    funcionario *novos = malloc(sizeof(funcionario));
    pessoas *outra = malloc(sizeof(pessoas));
    strcpy(outra->nome, nome);
    outra->idade = idade;
    novos->pessoa = outra;
    novos->prox = p;

    return novos;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que está implementado, não é o jeito correto, seguindo a hierarquia de banco de dados:

```
|-------------|              |--------|
| Funcionário |------1-N-----| Pessoa |
|-------------|              |--------|
```

A implementação da lista deveria ser a mesma coisa:

```
typedef struct Pessoas {
    char nome[20];
    int idade;
    struct Pessoas *prox;
}pessoas;

typedef struct Funcionario {
    pessoas *pessoa;
}funcionario;
```

ou:

```
typedef struct Funcionario {
    char nome[20];
    int idade;
    struct Funcionario *prox;
}funcionario;
```

Onde a cada pessoa inseria, irá acrescentar + 1 funcionário.

A partir do momento em que se coloca uma lista dentro de outra, sua estrutura para de ser uma lista e passa a ser um ***[Grafo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_dos_grafos)***

```
typedef struct _grafo{
    struct grafo next;
    struct grafo child;
    struct grafo parent;
}grafo;
```

Que é semelhante a sua estrutura.

Usando uma estrutura de *Grafo*, (assim como a que você está usando), é viável utilizar caso tenha funcionários diferentes.

```
typedef struct Pessoas {

    char nome[20];
    int idade;
    struct Pessoas *prox;
}pessoas;

typedef struct Funcionario {
    pessoas *pessoa;
    char *setor;
    float salario;
    /* ... */
    struct Funcionario *prox;
}funcionario;
```

Então nessa estrutura é possível cadastrar tipos diferentes de funcionários.